# sql server variant data type is not supported in spring boot when I set the hibernate dll auto to update

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot jpa with sql server. on hibernate-dll-auto **create** mode every thing is good. until I change the hibernate-dll-auto to **update**. and the exception throw is like:
*sql server variant data type is not supported*
I don't know how to fix this issue. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using old Spring tool suite. Please download new Spring tool suite and try again.

Comment: thanks for your attention. yes, I just changed the version and every thing is okey.